# How to aggregate query on related table's field in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.4

I have a One To Many (Inverse) relation on my laravel 5.4 application. There are two models `Sale` and `Vehicle` which are related and associated with the scene.

The relation on the `Sale` model is :

```
public function vehicle()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Vehicle','vehicle_id');
    }
```

Table `sales` has following fields :
`id`, `vehicle_id`, `date_time`, `status` etc.

Table `vehicles` has following fields :
`id`, `reg_number`, `volume`, `status` etc.

What I want is, sum of the field 'vehicles.volume' of `Sale` records within the search conditions.

I have tried some methods like the following one:

```
$query = Sale::where('status', 1);
$query = $query->where('date_time', '<', "2017-05-10 10:10:05");
$totalVolume  = $query->whereHas('vehicle')->sum('vehicles.volume');
```

and it resulted in the following error:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
>   'vehicles.volume' in 'field list' (SQL: select
>   sum(`vehicles`.`volume`) as aggregate from `sales` where `status` = 1
>   and `date_time` < "2017-05-10 10:10:05" and exists (select * from `vehicles` where `sales`.`vehicle_id` =
>   `vehicles`.`id`))

hopefully waiting for a solution to 'get the sum of the volume of the sales' using eloquent query.

- **Edited**

Comment: I think you should start off by just writing out the raw MySQL query which you would run if you were using Workbench directly.  Then, based on that, build the Laravel query.  If you can't write the MySQL query then you're probably not ready to attack the Laravel side of things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a join before summing the `vehicles.volume` column

```
$totalVolume = Sale::where('status', 1)
    ->where('date_time', '<', "2017-05-10 10:10:05")
    ->join('vehicles', 'vehicles.id', '=', 'sales.vehicle_id')
    ->select(DB::raw('sum(vehicles.volume) as total_volume');
```

Comment: Thank you Martin..

`$totalQuantity = $totalQuantityQuery->join('vehicles', 'vehicles.id', '=', 'sales.vehicle_id')->select(\DB::raw('sum(vehicles.volume) as total_volume'))->get()`
gives an object inside an array.. extracted the result using..
`$totalQuantity[0]->total_volume`

Answer (score 0):

```
select sum(volume) as aggregate from vehicles INNER JOIN sales ON vehicles.id=sales.vehicle_id
```